# table sorting not working after append the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to short the table even I append some values in table.Now I have created a sample which is sorting in double click.If I click 'ok'  button I have cleared the table and append with new values.Newly appended value doesn't get sorting

```js
 $(document).ready(function() { 
     $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
   
      $('#filter_records').click(function(){
   $('#myTable').html('');
   var html = "<thead class='thead-inverse'><tr>" +
   "<th>name</th>"+ 
   "<th><strong>Count</strong></th>" +
   
            "</tr></thead>";
   
   for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
    html = html + "<tbody><tr>"+
    "<td>name" +i+"</td>" +
    "<td>count"+i+ "</td>" +
    "</tr></tbody>";
      } 
      $("#myTable").append(html);
     });
          });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.27.8/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <table id="myTable" border=1>
      <thead class="thead-inverse">
     <tr>
      <th>name</th>
   <th>count</th>
     </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>sample</td>
   <td>count</td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
      <td>sample1</td>
   <td>count1</td>
     </tr> 
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <button type="button" id="filter_records" class="btn btn-default1">Ok</button>
    </body>
  
</html>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vphap1p6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After append data you need to call table update function

```
$("#myTable").trigger("update");
$("#myTable").trigger("sorton",[sorting]);
```

For ref. you can take a look 
http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html

Please find updated fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ByGVE/49/

Comment: you can share current code using fiddle then we can update you r code